# Angular JS module created but not loaded

Tags: angularjs

My angular app works locally (html only) but fails once deployed onto the server. No console error. No 404 errors. Basically...the UI doesn't render. The batarang extension says "module was created but never loaded"...yet when I run my app on localhost it doesn't show that message in Batarang.

I've researched the other similar issues with that issue but none of the solutions match my issue where it only works on localhost and not the server...

```
var ll_app = angular.module("liveLetter", []);

ll_app.service("ExportService", function() 
{
    this.export = function(format)
    {

        //code
    };
});

ll_app.controller("MenuController", ["$scope", "$rootScope", "$sce", "ExportService", function($scope, $rootScope, $sce, ExportService)
{
    //code
}]);

ll_app.controller("DraftController", ["$scope", "$rootScope", function($scope, $rootScope)
{
    //code
}]);
```

Html....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Live Letter
    </title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans+Mono" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/app.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/app_kwikies.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="liveLetter">
  <div id="main_nav" ng-controller="MenuController" ng-class="loading ? 'default' : 'half_width'">  
    <p id="header_txt">{{ shuffled_text }}</p>
    <div id="menu_buttons" ng-show="!loading"> 
        <div class="menu_icon" ng-repeat="icon in icons">
            <span class="symbola" ng-bind-html="icon.html" title="{{icon.title}}" ng-class="active_key === icon.key ? 'active_icon' : 'default_icon'" ng-click="icon.click_fn($event)"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <span id="email" ng-show="!loading">rnirnber@gmail.com</span>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="DraftController">
    <div id="editor" ng-if="editable" contenteditable="true" ng-style="text_color_css">
        {{content}}
    </div>
    <div id="rgb_inputs" ng-if="editable" style="display: block">
        <input value="{{red}}" ng-blur="update_rgb(0, $event)" type="number" step="5" min="0" max="255" />
        <input value="{{green}}" ng-blur="update_rgb(1, $event)" type="number" step="5" min="0" max="255"/>
        <input value="{{blue}}" ng-blur="update_rgb(2, $event)" type="number" step="5" min="0" max="255" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the sequence in which you are loading javascript libraries?

Comment: jquery...some custom jquery plugin i wrote....angular, bootstrap, bootstrap dialog plugin....and then lastly my angular app's "app.js"

Comment: @rnirnber, could you please provide us your html code? No need to copy past all your codes, just need `ng-app` and links to to the libraries and custom module files.

Comment: thanks for the help i'm out of options. i'm modifying the original post to include the HTML right now....